# How to declare a property on an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, constructor

I want to create new instance of Constructor function that has got an object that contains arrays of object and inside one of the objects, I would like to map passed argument. I am getting errors like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

My code:

```js
function Constructor (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
  this.arg1 = arg1;
  this.arg2 = arg2;
  this.arg3 = arg3;
  this.arg4 = arg4;

  this.storage = {
    arg1: {
      open: arg2, 
      dataset: [{
        drink: arg3.map(drink => ({
          drink,
        food: arg4
        }))
      }]
    }
}};


var diner = new Constructor ('restaurant', 'daily', ['wine', 'beer', 'vodka'], 'bread');

console.log(diner.storage);
```

Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLeOLp?editors=1111

I corrected the typos.

How can I pass 'restaurant' into 'arg1' within `this.storage = { arg1: { ...`

Comment: shame on me! :(

Comment: How can I pass 'restaurant' into 'arg1' within `this.storage = { arg1: { ...`

Comment: Your question is unclear. You're *already* passing "restaurant" as `arg1`.

Comment: expected result is `this.storage = { restaurant: { ...`

Comment: Yep ok answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I pass 'restaurant' into 'arg1' within this.storage = { arg1: { ...

I can only assume you want to do this:

```js
function Constructor (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) {
  this.arg1 = arg1;
  this.arg2 = arg2;
  this.arg3 = arg3;
  this.arg4 = arg4;

  this.storage = {
    [arg1]: {
      open: arg2, 
      dataset: [{
        drink: arg3.map(drink => ({
          drink,
        food: arg4
        }))
      }]
    }
}};


var diner = new Constructor ('restaurant', 'daily', ['wine', 'beer', 'vodka'], 'bread');

console.log(diner.storage);
```

Which gives you a *property* on `storage` called `restaurant`.